# How to do port forwarding for GNS3 server (SSH tunneling)?

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a GNS3 server, and I'm trying to add iptable rules so that when someone on my team connects on port 1100, they get routed to an internal IP such as 192.168.122.2:22. This internal IP belongs to a bastion host of a GNS3 project. The end goal is to be able to shh into the internal IP addresses from a local machine.

This is how my IPTABLE looks (using fake public IP 1.2.3.4 for sake of example):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            1.2.3.4       tcp dpt:1100 to:192.168.122.2:22

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         
1    MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0          

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain LIBVIRT_PRT (0 references)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

From my local machine, I execute the command `ssh ubunut@1.2.3.4 -p1100`.
Ubuntu is the username needed to access the GNS3 project internal IP.

After executing this command, I get the following output on the GNS3 server (1.2.3.4):
`cloud@gns3:~$ connect_to 192.168.122.2 port 1100: failed.`

Seems like my SSH command is reaching the GNS3 server, and attempts to do a port forwarding. **However, it's attempting to forward to port 1100 instead of 22 for some reason? Can anyone identify why?**

Here's what I tried to far:

1. Set ipv4 port forwarding to 1
2. set GatewayPorts and AllowTcpForwarding to 1 in
3. ran on local machine (I think this changed some configs on the server) - `ssh -R 1.2.3.4:1100:192.168.122.2:22 cloud@1.2.3.4`
4. Added rule to IPtables using command `sudo iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --destination 1.2.3.4 --dport 1100 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:22`
5. Also added Masquerading: `sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using DNAT, it should be REDIRECT according to this source:

https://fabianlee.org/2018/09/17/iptables-running-service-as-non-root-iptables-to-forward-from-privileged-port/

So:

```
sudo iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --destination 1.2.3.4 --dport 1100 --jump REDIRECT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:22
```